# Django based blog

Tags: software-recommendation, blog, django

Is there a Django based blog available on the repositories of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. This is probably because there is still no clear one-best blogging engine, those that are good still recieve heavy development (so are better suited to a git/svn/other VCS) so you can update more frequently, and because you can write your own (with a lot of features) in 10 minutes.

You can see all the django packages either in the Software Centre or by typing:

```
apt-cache search django
```

Comment: Any recommendation regarding a Django based blog that play nicely with Ubuntu then?

Comment: Sorry, no. Every time I have implemented a django blog, I just did it myself.

Comment: But this might help: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/